# Drizzle Studio : There is not enough information to infer relation

Tags: postgresql, sveltekit, drizzle

I'm trying to launch drizzle studio but I get the following error :

`Error: There is not enough information to infer relation "restaurantsTable.categories"`

What have I done wrong ?

**schema.ts**

```js
export const restaurantsTable = pgTable("restaurants", {
  id: serial("id").primaryKey(),
  [...]
});

export const restaurantTableRelations = relations(restaurantsTable, ({ one, many }) => ({
  menu: many(menuTable),
  categories: many(categoryTable, { relationName: 'categories' }),
}));

export const categoryTable = pgTable("categories", {
  id: serial("id").primaryKey(),
  restaurant_id: integer('restaurant_id').notNull()
});

export const categoryTableRelations = relations(categoryTable, ({ one }) => ({
  menu: one(menuTable, {
    fields: [categoryTable.restaurant_id],
    references: [menuTable.id],
    relationName: 'menu'
  })
}));
```

Answer (score 9):

Faced the same issue, turns out they're strict on defining the `relationName` on both sides as [mentioned in here](https://www.answeroverflow.com/m/1180072254214766632)

Ensuring it's defined on both sides solved my issue